# Custom InputFile in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazorinputfile

I want to replace the InputFile's rectangle with 'attach Icon'. I tried to set the URL of the icon to 'background-image' of InputFile but it had no effect.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65239461/can-i-replace-the-button-displayed-by-blazors-inputfile-component-with-another) only demonstrates how to change the color of InputFile, not exactly what I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825731/437393 Make your input transparent, e.g. opacity = 0, create another control, e.g. label, that will redirect click to your input. Apply some styles to label.

Comment: @Anonymous Worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you are looking for.

**HTML/Razor code**

```
<div class="file-input-zone">
    <InputFile />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
.file-input-zone {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: url('paper-clip.png');
}

    .file-input-zone:hover {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .file-input-zone input[type=file] {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

In the CSS code above, the file paper-clip.png is installed in wwwroot directory.

The button will look like a transparent paper-clip.  In the image below, color changes on hover as well.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I use something similar for a colour picker.

```
<label for="fileinput" class="label-wrapper">
    <span class="oi oi-paperclip"></span>
    <InputFile id="fileinput" class="custom-input-hide" />
</label>

<style>
    .label-wrapper:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .custom-input-hide {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GlOKuWww26fg0izh11)

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution and for sharing that online resource.  It looks nice for prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<label for="inputFile" class="btn btn-secondary me-1">
    <InputFile id="inputFile" OnChange="@LoadFiles" class="d-none" />
    Upload File
</label>
```

CSS Classes from `bootstrap`, included by default in the Blazor templates.